# Accepting input in user defined datatype

Tags: java, arraylist, user-input

I am writing a program to implement Dijkstra's algorithm (the shortest path between a node and every other node in the graph). I want the source node which is given by the user as input to be read as vertex (user defined datatype).

The following is my program:

```
import java.util.*;

class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>
{
    public final String name;
    public Edge[] adjacencies;
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Vertex previous;

    public Vertex(String argName) { 
        name = argName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
        return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }
}

class Edge
{
    public final Vertex target;
    public final double weight;

    public Edge(Vertex argTarget, double argWeight) { 
        target = argTarget;
        weight = argWeight;
    }
}

public class DijExample
{
    public static void computePaths(Vertex source) {
        /*This function computes the shortest distance*/
    }

    public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target){

        /*This function computes the shortest path*/
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sn;

        Vertex v0 = new Vertex("S");
        Vertex v1 = new Vertex("A");
        Vertex v2 = new Vertex("B");
        Vertex v3 = new Vertex("C");
        Vertex v4 = new Vertex("D");
        Vertex v5 = new Vertex("E");
        Vertex v6 = new Vertex("F");
        Vertex v7 = new Vertex("G");
        Vertex v8 = new Vertex("H");
        Vertex v9 = new Vertex("I");
        Vertex v10 = new Vertex("J");
        Vertex v11 = new Vertex("K");
        Vertex v12 = new Vertex("L");


        v0.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v1,5),new Edge(v2,7),new Edge(v3,1),new Edge(v4,3),new Edge(v5,2),new Edge(v6,6)};
        v1.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v0,5),new Edge(v5,4),new Edge(v6,7)};
        v2.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v0,7),new Edge(v10,6),new Edge(v11,2)};
        v3.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v0,1), new Edge(v11,1)};
        v4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v0,3),new Edge(v7,7)};
        v5.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v0,2),new Edge(v8,5)};
        v6.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v0,6),new Edge(v1,7),new Edge(v9,3)};
        v7.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v4,7)};
        v8.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v5,5)};
        v9.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v6,3)};
        v10.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v2,6),new Edge(v11,8),new Edge(v12,1)};
        v11.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v2,2),new Edge(v3,1),new Edge(v10,8),new Edge(v12,3)};
        v12.adjacencies = new Edge[]{new Edge(v10,1),new Edge(v11,3)};

        Vertex[] vertices = { v0,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10,v11,v12 };

        System.out.println("Enter the source node");
        sn = in.next();//Here sn is read as a string but I want to read it as a vertex

        computePaths(sn);//Calling the function to calculate the shortest path with the source node (of type vertex)

        for (Vertex v : vertices){
            System.out.println("Distance to " + v + ": " + v.minDistance);
            List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(v);
            System.out.println("Path: " + path);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your question is about translating a user input into the custom type, and not about the algorithm itself.
The trivial answer is to change your:

```
sn = in.next();
```

To

```
Vertex vn = new Vertex (in.next());
```

This gives you a new vertex, but it's not in the arry you've constructed and you don't have an easy way to find if there is a matching one there.  You are also subject to bad input.

A more usable mechanism might be to change your collection of Vertices to a `Map` of some sort (maybe `HashMap<String,Vertex>`), keyed on the `Vertex.name`.

You'd add your Vertex objects to it like `Vertices.add (v0.name, v0);`

Then you can check if the user has specified a valid Vertex - going back to reading a string:

```
Vertex vn = null;
sn = in.next();


if (Vertices.contains(sn)) {
  vn = Vertices.get(sn);
} else {
  System.out.println ("That's not a vertex I know about");
  System.exit(1);
}
```